# Change the anchor tag in CLEditor

Tags: jquery, wysiwyg, cleditor

Im using CLEditor on my website ([CLEditor](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/)) and it is working well only I want to be able to set the target of links to _blank but I can't figure it out, even when looking into the source.

Is there someone who can help me make the links made by the editor have a target of _blank

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the attribute to each link:

```
$("#cleeditor iframe").contents().find("a[href]").attr("target", "_blank");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you suggest to run the function before submit? I can see this working but I can imagine there would be a cleaner solution by changing the way the button works. But I can't understand the source code completely :$. I'll implement this for the time being, thanks.

Comment: I am still hoping for a better answer. When it doesn't come today I will use (and check) this solution.

Comment: There might not be anyone willing to go through CLE's code and see how to handle the URL creaton

Comment: I understand, so I will work with you answer for the time being.

Comment: Do you need to do .each?  Can't you just do `$("#cleeditor iframe]").contents().find("a[href]").attr('target','blank');`

Comment: @Paul probably, yes, since in my experience jQuery tries to be as chainable as possible.

Comment: @mattcurtis exactly, jQuery *is* extremely chainable, to the point where you can just chain the `attr("target", "blank")` without doing the `each` (which breaks the chain and introduces a new looping function).

Comment: Very few people still shackled to CLEditor these days (one would hope!), but this may still come in handy — helped me!

Answer (score 2):

```
$('textarea').cleditor({
  updateTextArea: function(html) {
    var e = $('<div>').append(html);
    e.find('a[href]').attr('target', '_blank');
    return e.html();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(function($) {

// Define the lien button
$.cleditor.buttons.lien = {
    name: "lien",
    image: "lien.gif",
    title: "Add link",
    command: "inserthtml",
    popupName: "Lien",
    popupClass: "cleditorPrompt",
    popupContent: 'Enter URL:<br><input type=text value="http://" size=35><br><input type=button value="submit">',
    buttonClick: lienClick
};

// Add the button to the default controls before the bold button
$.cleditor.defaultOptions.controls = $.cleditor.defaultOptions.controls
.replace("link", "lien link");

// Handle the lien button click event
function lienClick(e, data) {

    // Get the editor
    var editor = data.editor;

    if (editor.selectedText() === "") {
        editor.showMessage("A selection is required when inserting a link.");             
        return false;
    }

    // Wire up the submit button click event
    $(data.popup).children(":button")
    .unbind("click")
    .bind("click", function(e) {

        // Get the entered name
        var url = $(data.popup).find(":text").val();     
        var value = '<a href="' + url + '" target="_blank">' + editor.selectedText() + '</a>'
        var success = editor.doc.execCommand("insertHTML", 0, value || null)

        if (!success){
            editor.showMessage("Error executing the insertHTML command.");
        }
        // Hide the popup and set focus back to the editor
        editor.hidePopups();
        editor.focus();

    });      
}     
})(jQuery);
```

Just add this button or in cleditor replace in function execCommand :

```
try { 
      if(command.toLowerCase() == "createlink"){
        value = '<a href="' + value + '" target="_blank">' + getRange(editor) + '</a>'
        success = editor.doc.execCommand("insertHTML", 0, value || null);
      }else{
         success = editor.doc.execCommand(command, 0, value || null); 
      }
  }
```